# Angular Application to Accepts posts from an external application ( Similar to API )

Tags: angular, api, router

I need some guidance and if this scenario even possible. ( This is an MVP for a Client)

This Web application needs to **accepts** posts. Similar to how API works at Serverside. A third party application needs to post data in the form of JSON or text to my application, then I need to get the coming post data, do some cleaning and show it on the view.

No Server side can be used.

Query string is easy to get from the URL however the size of the query strings are very limited so I left with post method.

Any suggestion? Can it be done in Angular?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options for pushing data to your webapp.

- Use websockets, see e.g. https://medium.com/@lwojciechowski/websockets-with-angular2-and-rxjs-8b6c5be02fac
- Use a service worker and web-push notifications. Service worker can perform actions in the background even if the app is not active. There is an official angular implementation, that integrates well with the @angular/cli, see [docs](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro)